# Setting anchor target dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a WordPress theme that includes a widget for adding social media links into your sidebars/headers etc.

All of the social links are wrapped in a div with a unique class, `social-links`.

I would like to add `target="_blank"` to ALL of the anchors inside the `social-links` div.

So basically, `<a href="facebook.com">Facebook</a>` would change to `<a href="facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>`, providing that the `social-links` div was it's parent.

Let's say for this instance I don't have time to search around in thousands of lines of code to find where the social media links are being created for the widget, how would I go about dynamically adding the attribute with a class selector in jQuery?

I can use the code below to set attributes directly by using their class or id, but the links don't have unique classes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".class").attr("target", "_blank"); //here I need a way to select all anchors that have the .social-links div as a parent
});
```

And here's an example of the HTML for reference:

```
<div class="social-links">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/">Twitter</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: I also just found `$( ".class" ).children()`, but this would apply the attribute to all children inside `.class`, where as I only want to apply it to anchors. How can I also select via tag? Or is there a better/more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `target="_blank"` to all anchors inside the `.social-links` div you can use `.each()` and `.attr()` methods:

```
$(".social-links a").each(function() { // use $.each to loop through all a tags inside div
   $(this).attr("target","_blank"); // use .attr() to add attribute
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, just had to change `.social-links a` to `.social-links li a` as I forgot the links were actually direct parents of `li`